# Laptop on Fedora 16 running hot

Tags: linux, fedora, battery

Since switching from Windows 7 to Fedora 16, my laptop has been running incredibly hot (by the air exhaust).  The laptop is an Asus K73S.

Running `sensors`, I receive:

```
acpitz-virtual-0: 75.0 celsius
nouveau-pci-0100: 66.0 celsius
asus-isa-0000: 75.0 celsius
```

The only CPU hog is Firefox at 30 - 40% on average.

My GPU information (from lspci) is: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Process or Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09).

Running `lspci | grep -i VGA`, returns:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GF106 [GeForce GT 555M SDDR3] (rev a1)
```

I don't notice a huge difference running without the battery, but it does seem a little cooler.

Comment: 1) What is your question? 2) 75C is not that hot...

Comment: My question is how come it is running so hot / how do I make it not run as hot?

It's too hot to hold on my lap or have anything near the exhaust.

Comment: If your computer is getting so hot that it's uncomfortable to handle, you most likely have a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2):

It might be you have been collecting dust overtime, this reduces the cooling capabilities. Dust it out.

Also try this:

```
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

Comment: That would not be OS dependant....

Comment: It might not be OS dependent at all, I thought the might be elsewhere.

Comment: That will be OS dependent because different OSes have different power management algorithms. The most likely explanation is dust or a failed/failing fan.